# Get Index of Element with specific (unique) class in HTMLCollection

Tags: javascript, html, ecmascript-6, htmlcollection

In the Title.

HTML:

```
<div class="active"></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

Javascript (Vanilla):

```
// source HTML collection, only get the elements index which has the class "active"
let theCollection = document.querySelectorAll('div'); 

// related HTML collection
let anotherCollection = document.querySelectorAll('div .anotherClass');
// adding the class the corresponding element
theCollection[index].classList.add('active');
```

What I need to get is the index of the element which currently has the `active` class within `theCollection`.

Comment: What is `anotherCollection` for? Is it relevant to the question?

Comment: Why are you using `querySelectorAll` if your target is an unique div? Also, you can omit "div" from the selector, like this: `let anotherCollection = document.querySelector('.anotherClass');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To accomplish your task:

> "What I need to get is the index of the element which currently has the active class within theCollection."

you can loop over the divs and check to see which div has the active class. Please run the code to verify.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('div').forEach((item, index) => {
  if (item.classList.contains('active')) {
    document.getElementById('showActiveIndex').textContent = `index is ${index}`;
  }
})
```

```html
<div>zero</div>
<div>one</div>
<div class="active">two</div>
<div>three</div>
<hr />
<div id="showActiveIndex"></div>
```

Comment: Wow I totally forgot about this option... I was working quite a bit, so my brain isn't fully functioning anymore.
Thanks for the help!

Comment: I'm glad to assist. If the answer is correct, don't forget to mark it as such.

Answer (score 0):

If I unserstood correctly, you want to append the `active` class to the `div` that comes after the `div` who has the `active` class.

Why not just select all the corresponding divs and directly add the active class to them?

```
document.querySelectorAll('div.active + div').classList.add('active'); // selects all the div that comes after divs who have the .active class
```